# Focus on html element after it is enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I've got the following problem: I would like to focus on an input. But I have a spinner that is fired on page load and is hidden only when certain http requests are done. Also all inputs are disabled till requests are not done. So it looks like this:

```
<fieldset ng-disabled="!noPendingRequests">
    ...
    <input id="input-to-focus-on" uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" type="text" ng-model="startDate" ... />
    <spinner ng-hide="noPendingRequests"></spinner>
</fieldset>
```

Spinner is a custom Angular directive. There is a requirement to autofocus on `#input-to-focus-on` input but it doesn't work. I tried to focus right after all the http requests are resolved using `$q.all`. But that doesn't work too. I guess it happens because a callback in `$q` is fired before the input gets enabled. I also tried manual enabling like this:

```
$q.all(somePromises).then(function() {
    angular.element('#input-to-focus-on')[0].disabled = false;
    angular.element('#input-to-focus-on')[0].tabIndex = 1;
    angular.element('#input-to-focus-on').focus();
 });
```

I have no idea what to do and would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: Might be worth trying [ngFocus directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus) as it is built for the Angular flow.

Comment: @GillesC thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't work too

Comment: @GillesC how about this one https://gist.github.com/zbicin/2b3fdf538936287c1a96 ? I've made it some time ago to serve this purpose.

Comment: can you provide us with the directive, and are sure you set noPendingRequests to false when the request done ?

Comment: @Krzysztof Zbiciński thank you, it is an interesting thing but I can't get it to work

Comment: @Ahmad Abo Saa I'm absolutely sure noPendingRequests is true when all the requests are done because all the inputs the fieldset become enabled and the spinner disappears.

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich this is a working jsBin, my be can help you https://jsbin.com/zeremateji/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Ahmad Abo Saa I understand, of course. But the solution below looks much more attractive for me in terms of lines of count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the focus call in a `$timeout` block.

```
$timeout(function () {
  angular.element('#input-to-focus-on').focus();
});
```

Comment: It works! It really works, man!!! I cannot express how much I'm glad you came here and wrote this answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
$q.all(somePromises).then(function() {
   $timeout(function () {
      angular.element('#input-to-focus-on')[0].focus();
    });
});
```

Also, make sure you have $timeout injected into your controller.